# How to deal with empty fields in scrapy when using keys

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have made a spider in scrapy that can successfully scrape data from a website.

```
   def parse(self, response):
            for text in response.css('div.row'):
                yield {
                    'product': text.css('div.item a.item::text').get(),
                    'test1': text.css('div.item span::text')[0].get(),
                    'test2': text.css('div.item span::text')[1].get(),
```

This is not the complete code, but this should be enough to explain the problem.

The problem occurs when the `'test2': text.css('div.item span::text')[1].get(),` is empty.

It will give an `IndexError: list index out of range`, which makes sense. But how can I check if the value is empty so I can replace it with a default?

1. I know the `get()` has a default parameters `get(default='')`, unfortunately because I use keys `[0]` this parameters is not available.
2. I was looking into `ternary expressions` but I could not find a way to do this inside which I think is a dictionary.

Comment: first get `item = text.css()`, next check `if len(item) > 0` before you use `[0]` and `if len(item) > 1` before you use `[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get `items = text.css(...)`,

next check `if len(items) > 0` before you use `items[0]`
and `if len(items) > 1` before you use `items[1]`

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for text in response.css('div.row'):
            items = text.css('div.item span::text')
            yield {
                'product': text.css('div.item a.item::text').get(),
                'test1': items[0].get() if len(items) > 0 else "",
                'test2': items[1].get() if len(items) > 1 else "",
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use CSS `:nth-of-type(1)` instead of `[0]` in `a.item:nth-of-type(1)::text`

```
'div.item a.item:nth-of-type(1)::text'
```

Or xpath with `[1]`

```
'(.//div[@class="item"]/a[@class="item"])[1]/text()'
```

---

`Scrapy` uses module [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so I created minimal working code with `parsel`

```
text = '''
<div class="item">
<a class="item" href="a">a</a>
<a class="item" href="b">b</a>
</div>
'''

import parsel

s = parsel.Selector(text)

print(s.css('div.item a.item:nth-of-type(1)::text').get('empty')) # a
print(s.css('div.item a.item:nth-of-type(2)::text').get('empty')) # b
print(s.css('div.item a.item:nth-of-type(3)::text').get('empty')) # empty


print(s.xpath('(.//div[@class="item"]/a[@class="item"])[1]/text()').get('empty'))
print(s.xpath('(.//div[@class="item"]/a[@class="item"])[2]/text()').get('empty'))
print(s.xpath('(.//div[@class="item"]/a[@class="item"])[3]/text()').get('empty'))
```

Comment: I added example with CSS selector `:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: `:nth-of-type(1)` solution results in a `TypeError: text argument should be of type <class 'str'>, got <class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>` the same goes for the `xpath` solution.

Comment: I don't have working code with Scrapy to test it - maybe it uses it in different way.

Comment: If I use `text.xpath` it works, but only if when I use `[1]` like so `text.xpath('(.//div[@class="item"]/a[@class="item"])[1]/text()').get('empty')`. 
The same goes for the `:nth-of-type` solution, it will work with text like so `text.css('div.item a.item:nth-of-type(1)::text').get('empty')` but only if I use `(1)`

Comment: I don't understanw - what gives you error? How did you use it ?

Comment: I used it in the same way as you described, but without the `parcel selector`. Instead I used `text` like I showed in my question. But your first solution is working like it should. So I am good to go!